# What can go into the FAQ to help people not get confused about there being questions and answers from other sects?

Tags: discussion, faq-content

I propose that we put in the FAQ something saying that there will be questions and answers here from other sects, so to not be confused. What I would like to do, is to get some suggestions for the exact text to add into the faq that fulfills the purpose I described above, and after getting some suggestions we get some consensus on which one is the best by voting on them.

Comment: An excellent idea!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Islam.StackExchange welcomes **all** sects and groups that identify themselves as Muslim. **Do** expect to see answers from multiple points of view, unless a certain point of view is *specifically* requested in the question. **Don't** get into *"your sect/group is wrong"* debates and respect other people's beliefs.

Comment: as there seems to be no dispute on this, i have added it to [the FAQ](http://islam.stackexchange.com/faq) (with minor tweaks for clarity)